# Installing one video card driver in Linux uninstalls the other video card driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-10.04, graphics-card

I'm trying to use dual-monitors in Linux. One monitor is connected to an on-board graphics card, which uses the fglrx driver, and another to a PCI-E card, which uses the nvidia driver. I have successfully used this for a multi-monitor setup in Windows, and am trying to do the same thing in Linux.

In Ubuntu 10.04 I install video card drivers by going to System->Administration->Hardware Drivers. The problem is that when it installs one video card driver, it seems to uninstall the other video card driver, so I'm only able to run off of one video card but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this happen if you install the other driver via *Ubuntu Software Center*?

Comment: If I install the driver from the Ubuntu Software Center it doesn't uninstall the other driver but it doesn't seem to make any changes to the system either.